# How should subscription topic be be organized in mqtt broker?

Tags: mqtt, iot

I am creating my own implementation of mqtt broker (I know there are few existing, but I need realy tiny one - for embeded project). I wonder how sholud  topic be organised - should I store topic list and connect clients IDs for  particular topic or should every client instance has its own list of subscribed topic? What is better aproach?

Comment: Asking "which is best" type questions tend to lead to opinion based answers which are off topic for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it would be better to go for storing clients and fetching the ones with matching topic when a message is received.

This will help incase you are using the # wildcard.

Also If you store topics and attach clients to them, then you will have to go to multiple topics each with multiple clients for every message you receive.

But if you store the clients and link the topic to them, you will have to iterate through the list of clients and then go for 1 topic each. I see that as one less for loop.